# Configuring R with GRASS GIS

Tags: windows, r, geospatial, spatial, grass

I just started using GRASS GIS 7.0.0beta2. I want to use R in GRASS and vise versa. Following the instructions from [here](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics), when I bring the WinGRASS-windows console in front and type R for opening a R-session (command line mode) inside a GRASS-session, I get the following error:

```
sh.exe": R: command not found
```

How can I configure R and GRASS so that I can use R in GRASS and GRASS in R. I'm on `Windows 7` with `R 3.1.0` and `GRASS GIS 7.0.0beta2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Linux user, so I can't try it, but it seems to me that R bins directory is not in your  `PATH`.

To test it, open a command line (should be `cmd.exe`) and try

```
R
```

If the output is the same as above, then add R bin directory to `PATH`, so you can call R from whatever directory you want.

Check one of the [following links](https://www.google.it/search?q=add+directory+to+path+windows+7) and apply it to the directory where R bins reside.

HTH, let me know. Luca

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Luca for your helpful answer. It works for calling R but struggling to call GRASS in R (Please see the provide link). Any idea.

Comment: have you installed spgrass6? which commands do not work and what's the output?

Comment: Yes, I have installed `spgrass6`. My `GRASS` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS 7.0.0beta2`. When I use `library(spgrass6)`, I get `GRASS GIS interface loaded with GRASS version: (GRASS not running)`. I tried to initialize the `GRASS` in `R` with `initGRASS("C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS GIS 7.0.0beta2", home=tempdir())` and this produces the following error message `Error in system(paste("g.dirseps.exe -g", shQuote(Sys.getenv("WINGISRC"))),  :  'g.dirseps.exe' not found`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Got it with the following code: `loc <- 
  initGRASS(
  # "C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS GIS 6.4.3"
   "C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS GIS 7.0.0beta2"
  , home=getwd()
  , gisDbase="GRASS_TEMP"
  , override=TRUE
  )` borrowed from [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/93105/19263).